# Python How to add print exception that the website supports my defined protocol

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

How can I print errors if the tls protocol I've used isn't supported by the website I'm targeting? And how can I print that the tls protocol is supported? 

I have no idea how to add an exception. Everytime an error happens it says `"Connection has been terminated by the external host"`, which means that the tls protocol isn't supported and when the protocol is supported nothing happens.

```
import socket
import ssl


context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='www.verisign.com')
ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic exception

```
try:
    ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
except Exception as e:
    print("error: %s" %e)
```

But is not usual to request URL by socket connection low level, you can use some library (requests or curl) to request for URL